# Fixing navigation bar's dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

You can take a look at the page I'm working on here:

http://www.privateservercloud.com/

Here's a link to the CSS file being used:
http://www.privateservercloud.com/style.css

Here's the code for the HTML:

```
<div class="navbar whmcscontainer" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <div class="menu" style="text-align: center;">
<ul style="padding: 0;" id="treemenu1">
    <ul class="nav" style="width:158px">
      <li><a href="#">SEO Dashboard</a>
        <ul style="margin-left:-1px;width:152px;">
            <li style="width:152px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:152px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:152px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:152px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav" style="width:186px">
      <li><a href="#">Manage Campaigns</a>
        <ul style="margin-left:-1px;width:180px;">
            <li style="width:180px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:180px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:180px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:180px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:180px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:180px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:180px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:180px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav" style="width:175px">
      <li><a href="#">Reporting System</a>
        <ul style="margin-left:-1px;width:169px;">
            <li style="width:169px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:169px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:169px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:169px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:169px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:169px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:169px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:169px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav" style="width:165px">
      <li><a href="#">General Settings</a>
        <ul style="margin-left:-1px;width:159px;">
            <li style="width:159px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:159px; margin-left:5px;padding:8px 0 6px 4px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:159px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:159px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:159px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:159px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:159px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:159px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav" style="width:158px">
      <li><a href="#">Support Center</a>
        <ul style="margin-left:-1px;width:152px;">
            <li style="width:152px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:152px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:152px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:152px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:152px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav" style="width:159px">
      <li style="border-right:0;"><a href="#">Account Details</a>
        <ul style="margin-left:-1px;width:153px;">
            <li style="width:153px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:153px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:153px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:153px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:153px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:153px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
            <li style="width:153px"><a href="test.php"><span style="width:153px; margin-left:5px;">Test Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the code for the Javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document
var menuids=["treemenu1"] 
function buildsubmenus_horizontal(){

for (var i=0; i<menuids.length; i++){
  var ultags=document.getElementById(menuids[i]).getElementsByTagName("ul")
    for (var t=0; t<ultags.length; t++){
        if (ultags[t].parentNode.parentNode.id==menuids[i]){ //if this is a first level submenu
            ultags[t].style.top=ultags[t].parentNode.offsetHeight+"px" //dynamically position first level submenus to be height of main menu item
            ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className="mainfoldericon"
        }
        else{ //else if this is a sub level menu (ul)
          ultags[t].style.left="0px" //position menu to the right of menu item that activated it
        ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className="subfoldericon"
        }
    ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover=function(){
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility="visible"
    }
    ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout=function(){
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility="hidden"
    }
    }
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", buildsubmenus_horizontal, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", buildsubmenus_horizontal)
```

Here's the code for the CSS:

```
.navbar {
position:relative;
background:#2FA4E7;
background-image:linear-gradient(tobottom,rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(251,253,255,0) 78% rgba(250,253,255,0));
-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2), inset 0 -3px 3px rgba(1,2,2,.11), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2), inset 0 -3px 3px rgba(1,2,2,.11), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2), inset 0 -3px 3px rgba(1,2,2,.11), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
font-size:110%;
margin-bottom:15px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.navbar .nav {
position:relative;
left:0;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
float:left;
margin:0;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
display:block;
padding:15px 23px;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
visibility: visible;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
color:#ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar li {
border-left:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.05);
border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.nav-collapse .nav li a:hover {
background:url(images/hover.png)!important;
}

#whmcscontent .whmcscontainer {
background:#fff;
border:1px solid #ccc;
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
clear:both;
}

.menu ul li ul li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.menu ul li ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff !important;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    left: 0 !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 10px 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 51px !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 218px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.menu ul li ul li {
    background: url("images/nav_link.gif") no-repeat scroll left 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaecf2;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu ul li ul li a span {
    color: #516594;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font: 15px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0 6px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
}
.menu ul li ul li a:hover span {
    padding: 8px 0 6px 4px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Right now I'm working on a few issues and would appreciated any help that can be provided:

**Issue #1:**  I need to raise each drop down menu by about 5px.  Basically there's a lot of white above the first "Test Menu" option in each drop down menu and I'm trying to minimize that white space a bit more.  How can I raise it up by 5px and then just have blue navigation bar overlap it?

**Issue #2:**  When hovering over the options, you'll also notice that on the right side of each drop down menu, thee appears to be a thick border on the right side - at least thicker than the 1px I set it to.  What's causing that to happen?

**Issue #3:**  To the right of the "SEO Dashboard" link you'll notice that the right border fades after you hover and unhover.  How can I fix this so it stays the same?

Comment: Please post the relevant code here - your project might not be around as long as this question is.

Comment: Just updated it with that information.

Comment: I just got issue #1 fixed.  It can be ignored.

Comment: You have ul inside another ul ... add the li elements missing and adjust the css.

Comment: I really don't understand why you use a stylesheet when you can all do it inline in HTML like you already do! ;) Its easier to modify values, you just change a value in one line...and again for all other 50!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if you actually look at the code, you'll see that most of those values you're referring to are used just within that `ul` since every 'ul' is using a different width.

Comment: @Username :) ok, anyway if you already set a with to the parent like `<ul style="margin-left:-1px;width:152px;">` there's absolutely no reason to repeat that value for every single `LI`. There's no reason to set fixed widths at all. Too long to explain in the allowed number of characters. You'll know one day as soon you master CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue #1:** Line 123:

```
.menu ul li ul {
    /* ... */
    padding: 0px 0 10px 6px; /* decreases top space above the first "Test Menu" */
    top: 100% !important;    /* brings the menu flush with the blue nav bar */
    /* ... */
}
```

**Issue #2:** It is caused by the below. It looks thick because there are two 1px borders next to each other: the border on the `<ul>` and the border on the `<li>`. The solution for issue 3 also solves this issue.

```
.navbar li {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

**Issue #3:** I'm not sure why the border disappears after you unhover, but an easy fix is to move the following lines:

```
border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.05);
border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
```

From `.navbar li` to `.navbar .nav > li > a`. This is better practice since the `<li>` is parent of the popup, whereas the `a` is a sibling, so its borders won't interfere with the popup (cause for issue #2).

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1:  In the following ul element:

```
<ul style="padding: 0;margin-top: 5px !important;" id="treemenu1">
```

add the following CSS to that element:

```
margin-top: 5px;
```

Issue #2:  on line #103 of style.css, you have a border-right declaration

Issue #3:  fixing issue #2 above will also fix this issue

Comment: Looks like you already added the margin-top: 5px for issue #1